# In Spring4D how to ResolveAll IFactory, supplying an argument from the container?

Tags: delphi, dependency-injection, spring4d

I would like to call `GlobalContainer.ResolveAll<IFactory<TBob,IItem>>` to return me an array of IFactories which when supplied with a TBob with return me an IItem.

I have the IItems registered as

```
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IItem,TA>('A');
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IItem,TB>('B');
```

But I can't find a way to register the individual IFactories such as

```
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IFactory<TBob,IItem>('AFac',['A']);
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IFactory<TBob,IItem>('BFac',['B']);
```

as there is not an option to specify the 'injected' values.

The only way I can find to do it is to have code like below for each factory but am sure there must be a cleaner way.
In the following code I have found I have to use TFunc and not IFactory as although they both are in fact TFunc I get an AV.
Also by doing this method I have to mark the constructor with [Inject] if there are any other parameters in the IItem's constructor otherwise the resolver picks the inherited constructor.

```
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TFunc<TBob,IItem>>('AFac').DelegateTo(
    function: TFunc<TBob,IItem>
    begin
      Result:=function(Bob: TBob): IItem
      begin
        Result:=GlobalContainer.Resolve<IItem>('A',[Bob]);
      end;
    end
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factories are registered via `RegisterFactory` and they only support interfaces with methodinfo (`$M+` or inherited from `IInvokable`) or anonymous method type that have the methodinfo enabled such as `Func<...>` (recommended) from Spring.pas (introduced in 2.0) (not `TFunc<...>` from SysUtils.pas). That is because it uses the parameter info to dynamically build the factory code.

You did not explicitly stated that but I assume the constructors of `TA` and `TB` both look like this:

```
constructor Create(bob: TBob);
```

You then register them like this (keep in mind that this might not work when all code is in a simple test dpr because of some typeinfo glitches when they are inside the dpr) - the types being registered in the container need to be in a unit.

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IItem, TA>('A');
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IItem, TB>('B');
GlobalContainer.RegisterFactory<Func<TBob,IItem>>('AFactory', 'A', TParamResolution.ByType);
GlobalContainer.RegisterFactory<Func<TBob,IItem>>('BFactory', 'B', TParamResolution.ByType);
GlobalContainer.Build;
var factories := Globalcontainer.ResolveAll<Func<TBob,IItem>>;
for var factory in factories do
begin
  var item := factory(nil);
  Writeln((item as TObject).ClassName);
end;
```

This will print:

```
TA
TB
```

Comment: Thanks @StefanGlienke.  It certainly looks like what I wanted to do however have been unable to locate Func<> in Spring.pas.   I created my own as {$M+}
type
  Func<P1,P2> = reference to function (Value: P1): P2;
but got zero results.

Comment: After adding my own Func<> it did work.  I am interested in your version of Spring with the Func<>.  Is that Spring4D v2?